# how to foreach array to array object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, foreach

I'm very confused about doing foreach array to array object in Javascript, I already did a lot of research about foreach object in Javascript and I tried many ways but nothing works. All that I'm trying to achieve is to have data JSON like this :

```
[
            {
                "name": "First Data",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "y": 95,
                        "total":100,
                        "md": "1",
                        "name": "National",
                        "drillup" : 'level0',
                        "drilldown" : "3",
                        "next"  : "level2"
                    }

                ]
            }
            ,{
                "name": "Second Data",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "y": 95,
                        "total":100,
                        "md": "1",
                        "name": "National",
                        "drillup" : 'National',
                        "drilldown" : "3",
                        "next"  : "level2"
                    }

                ]
            }
        ]
```

and I tried to do foreach based on some finding of my research but the result wasn't like what I want or like what I'm try to achieve  ..
and here is the script that I tried :

```
  dataFirstSecond = await informationModel.getdata();
    Object.entries(dataRegularSecondary).forEach(entry => {
        const [key, value] = entry;
        returnData[key] = [
            {
                name: value.name,
                data: [{
                    y: value.y,
                    total: value.total_ada,
                    next: 'level_2',
                    drilldown: true,
                }]
            }]
    });
```

and here is the result or the output of my script that I try it :

```
{
    "0": [
        {
            "name": "First Data",
            "data": [
                {
                    "y": 22.973,
                    "total": 17,
                    "next": "level_2",
                    "drilldown": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "1": [
        {
            "name": "Second Data",
            "data": [
                {
                    "y": 5.4054,
                    "total": 4,
                    "next": "level_2",
                    "drilldown": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

can someone help me to achieve the data that I want?

Comment: `returnData[key] = [{ ... }]` should just be `returnData.push({ ... })`, and make sure `returnData` is an array (e.g. `returnData = []`

Comment: Can you show us what the result should be ?

Comment: Neither `dataRegularSecondary` or `resultData` exist in your code. Can you try to provide a [mcve] so we can debug it?

Comment: Is `dataRegularSecondary` really an object and not an array?

Comment: Where are you getting `value.y` from? Should it not be `value.data[0].y`? Or what does the data `dataFirstSecond` look like and, is it `dataFirstSecond` or `dataRegularSecondary `?

Comment: Hallo thankyou for your answer, i try your suggest and answer from @dave it;s work from me please update to answer to the post so i give your green check thanks for help me everyone gbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`returnData[key] = [{ ... }]` should just be `returnData.push({ ... })`, and make sure `returnData` is an array (e.g. `returnData = []`)

Answer (score 0):

If the function `informationModel.getdata();` returns an `Object` you could use the method `JSON.stringify(Object)` to easily convert and `Object` to `JSON`. For example you could try to do to convert this `Object` to a `String` then cast the `String` to `JSON`.

```
let JSONString = JSON.stringify(informationModel.getdata());
let JSON_Object = JSON.parse(JSONString);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, i found the best practice and check the comment from dave its work from gbu bro

Answer (score 0):

If `dataRegularSecondary` is an array and not an object you could use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
dataRegularSecondary.map(value => {
      return {
        name: value.name,
        data: [{
          y: value.y,
          total: value.total_ada,
          next: 'level_2',
          drilldown: true,
        }]
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for reply, can you suggest for this return change, include the variabel like php $data1[0] and $data1[2] dimenstional

Comment: Please clarify.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, i found the best practice and check the comment from dave its work from gbu bro

Answer (score 0):

Your question is `how to forEach array to array object`. Then that means `dataRegularSecondary` is an array, right? `Object.entries` returns an array of key value pairs. If you pass an array to that method, it will return the indices as keys and the items as values.

```
const arr = ['hello', 'world'];

Object.entries(arr); // [['0', 'hello'], ['1', 'world']]
```

Skip the `Object.entries` and use `dataRegularSecondary` directly for `forEach`.

As for your output, it looks like `returnData` is an object as well. Make sure it's an array and just push the data into that.

```
dataRegularSecondary.forEach(value => {
  returnData.push({
    name: value.name,
    data: [{
      y: value.y,
      total: value.total_ada,
      next: 'level_2',
      drilldown: true,
    }],
  });
});
```

Or you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as well.

```
const returnData = dataRegularSecondary.map(value => ({
  name: value.name,
  data: [{
    y: value.y,
    total: value.total_ada,
    next: 'level_2',
    drilldown: true,
  }],
}));
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, i found the best practice and check the comment from dave its work from gbu bro